# Azure sample application

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am running a azure storage program.

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/web-site-with-storage/

When I am running the application I am getting an error:

```
C:\node\Azuretablestorage2\models\task.js:16
        throw error;
              ^
ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at tableCreated (C:\node\Azuretablestorage2\models\task.js:16:15)
    at C:\node\Azuretablestorage2\node_modules\azure\lib\services\table\tableservice.js:268:5
    at C:\node\Azuretablestorage2\node_modules\azure\lib\services\table\tableservice.js:235:7
    at C:\node\Azuretablestorage2\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\serviceclient.js:534:11
    at C:\node\Azuretablestorage2\node_modules\azure\lib\services\table\tableservice.js:238:5
    at Request._callback (C:\node\Azuretablestorage2\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\serviceclient.js:197
    at C:\node\Azuretablestorage2\node_modules\azure\node_modules\request\main.js:122:22
    at Request.<anonymous> (native)
```

From the code it is from:

```
 this.storageClient.createTableIfNotExists(tableName, 
    function tableCreated(err) {
      if(err) {
        throw error;
```

I have azure installed but stil getting this Error ..any suggestions what could be the reason for this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that code is buggy. It should probably read `throw err;`. Once you're throwing the real error, you'll be able to see what the problem is (why you're getting an error in the first place.)

Comment: can you please suggest me how to get the sample program get working

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested? If so, what error did you get?

Comment: firstly thank you very much for the reply. actually I got the application as is from azure website . I could not throw the real Error becuase I am not able to make the application work

Comment: Change the text `throw error` to `throw err`. That will throw the real error.

Comment: its giving this Error:         throw err;
              ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
    at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:140:16). I basically took the sample program and than changed in server.js to : , accountName = 'azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'
  , accountKey = 'azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY';

Comment: also what is the difference between throw err and throw error

Comment: That looks like you're real error. You're trying to talk to cloud storage but using the credentials for the storage emulator. Perhaps you should start a new question and ask for help using the storage emulator.

Comment: The difference is just a typo. The sample code says "error," but the name of the variable is actually "err" (from `function tableCreated(err)`).

Comment: Thankq. I have posted a different question. so you think that is  typo on application right? as it always returns err

Comment: Yes, the sample has a typo. I've sent mail to someone at Microsoft about it.